# Simple Array & Loops in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am very new to Javascript and have no clue how to fulfill the following requests (in comments). If someone could please put me on the right track that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks. As you will see I have made attempts and there are comments inside the code and I need to figure out how to create what is asked.

```
          <h2>Three</h2>
          <button id="button-three">Output Colors</button>
          <ul id="color-list"></ul>
          <script>
          var mycolorlist = ['green','yellow','blue','red','brown','purple','pink']
          var colorlist = document.getElementById("color-list");
          var newLi = document.createElement("li");
          var copy = document.createTextNode(mycolorlist )
          newLi.appendChild (copy)
          /*
          1. Create an array with the seven colors of the rainbow
          2. Loop through the array and append an "li" for each color to the "color-list" ul
          */
          </script>



      <h2>Font Sizer</h2>
      <p id="to-style">This is my paragraph of stuff.</p><br>
      <input type="text" id="font-size" placeholder="Enter a font size"><button id="font-button">Make it so</button>
      <script>
      var imgchange = document.getElementById("kitten");
      var updatefont = document.getElementById("font-button");
      updatefont.addEventListener("click", myFunction);
      function myFunction(){
        document.getElementById("to-style").style.fontSize = "document.getElementById("font-size").value";
      }
      /*
      1. Get a font-size value from the text box and use it to change the font-size of "to-style"
      */
      </script>

      <h2>Element Counter</h2>
      <input type="text" id="element-type" placeholder="Which element?"><br>
      <button id="count">Count the Elements</button>
      <input type="text" id="element-count" placeholder="Results here" readonly="true">
      <script>
      /*
      1. Get the user input for an element, id, class, or query and display how many exist on the page in the Results box
      (use queryselectorall)
      */
      </script>

  <h2>Five</h2>
  <label>Input 1: <input type="text" id="input1"></label><br>
  <label>Input 2: <input type="text" id="input2"></label><br>
  <button id="button-compare">Compare</button>
  <script>
  var buttoncompare = document.getElementById("button-compare");
  var input1 = document.getElementById("input1");
  var input2 = document.getElementById("input2");
  buttoncompare.addEventListener("click", myFunction);
function myFunction(){ if (input1 == input2) {console.log('true');} else {console.log('false');}
}
  /*
  1. Add an event listener to the "button-compare" button
  2. When the button is clicked, compare the values of the two inputs
  3. Output to the console the results of the comparison (true or false)
  */
  </script>

<h2>Four</h2>
  <div id="box1" class="box">Mouse Events</div>
  <script>
  var box1 = document.getElementById("box1");
  box1.addEventListener("mouseover", myFunction);
function myFunction(){
  console.log('mouse entered the box');
  box1.addEventListener("mouseout", myFunction);
function myFunction(){
  console.log('mouse left the box');
}

  /*
  1. Add two event listeners to the box. One for when the mouse enters, the other when it leaves
  2. When the cursor enters the box, log to the console "Mouse entered the box".
  3. When the cursor leaves the box, log to the console "Mouse left the box".
  */
  </script>
```

Comment: problem 1. The same name `myFunction` is used for multiple functions

Comment: Problem 2: Brown is not one of the colours of the rainbow. Neither is pink.

Answer (score 0):

See the comments given in each function to see how it is working

```
<body>
    <h2>Three</h2>
    <button id="button-three">Output Colors</button>
    <ul id="color-list"></ul>
    <script>
        var mycolorlist = ['green','yellow','blue','red','brown','purple','pink']
        var colorlist = document.getElementById("color-list");
        //need to loop through the list and create the li elements
        for(var i = 0; i < mycolorlist.length; i++){
            var newLi = document.createElement("li");
            var copy = document.createTextNode(mycolorlist[i])
            newLi.appendChild (copy)
        }
        /*
        1. Create an array with the seven colors of the rainbow
        2. Loop through the array and append an "li" for each color to the "color-list" ul
        */
    </script>



    <h2>Font Sizer</h2>
    <p id="to-style">This is my paragraph of stuff.</p><br/>
    <input type="text" id="font-size" placeholder="Enter a font size"/><button id="font-button">Make it so</button>
    <script>
        var updatefont = document.getElementById("font-button");
        updatefont.addEventListener("click", fontSizeHandler);
        //you are using same function name every where
        function fontSizeHandler(){
            document.getElementById("to-style").style.fontSize = document.getElementById('font-size').value + 'px';
        }
        /*
        1. Get a font-size value from the text box and use it to change the font-size of "to-style"
        */
    </script>

    <h2>Element Counter</h2>
    <input type="text" id="element-type" placeholder="Which element?"/><br/>
    <button id="count">Count the Elements</button>
    <input type="text" id="element-count" placeholder="Results here" readonly="true"/>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("count").addEventListener("click", function(){
            var value = document.getElementById("element-type").value;
            //Using querySelectorAll will help us get elements matching the given css selectors.
            // ie for searching for id need to use the prefix #, for class use the prefix .
            //so input value #result will search for element with id result and .result will get elements with class result, where as just div will give all the div elements
            document.getElementById("element-count").value = document.querySelectorAll(value).length;
        });
        /*
        1. Get the user input for an element, id, class, or query and display how many exist on the page in the Results box
        (use queryselectorall)
        */
    </script>

    <h2>Five</h2>
    <label>Input 1: <input type="text" id="input1"/></label><br/>
    <label>Input 2: <input type="text" id="input2"/></label><br/>
    <button id="button-compare">Compare</button>
    <script>
        var buttoncompare = document.getElementById("button-compare");
        var input1 = document.getElementById("input1");
        var input2 = document.getElementById("input2");
        buttoncompare.addEventListener("click", function(){
            //need to compare value of the input elements
            console.log(input1.value == input2.value);
        });
        /*
        1. Add an event listener to the "button-compare" button
        2. When the button is clicked, compare the values of the two inputs
        3. Output to the console the results of the comparison (true or false)
        */
    </script>

    <h2>Four</h2>
    <div id="box1" class="box">Mouse Events</div>
    <script>
        var box1 = document.getElementById("box1");
        box1.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
            console.log('mouse entered the box');
        });
        box1.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
            console.log('mouse left the box');
        });

        /*
        1. Add two event listeners to the box. One for when the mouse enters, the other when it leaves
        2. When the cursor enters the box, log to the console "Mouse entered the box".
        3. When the cursor leaves the box, log to the console "Mouse left the box".
        */
    </script> 
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! a savior! One thing though, how can I get the rainbow to generate on a button click?

Answer (score 0):

```
<h2> It is the test case for generating rainbow using javascript </h2>    


<button value="Show Rainbow" onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>   

<br>   

<ul id="colors">    

</ul>  

<script>   

function myFunction() {

var array = ['green','yellow','blue','red','brown','purple','pink'];

for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++)    
{
var node = document.createElement("LI");   

var textnode = document.createTextNode(array[i]);   

node.appendChild(textnode);  

document.getElementById("colors").appendChild(node);   

}  

} 
</script>
```